# AppGrid saves all images in 'Downloads' folder

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu

I installed AppGrid and everything works great, but all apps images was saved in 'Downloads/appgrid' folder.

How can I change folder for image saving?

By the way, I'm using Lubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I edited file '/usr/share/appgrid/appdata/helpers.py', around line 11 there is:

```
if os.geteuid() != 0:
    dd = GLib.get_user_special_dir(GLib.UserDirectory.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOAD)
    downloads_dir = dd + '/appgrid/'
    if not os.path.exists(downloads_dir):
        os.mkdir(downloads_dir)
```

I comment out 'dd' and changed it to:

```
if os.geteuid() != 0:
 #   dd = GLib.get_user_special_dir(GLib.UserDirectory.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOAD)
    downloads_dir = '/tmp/appgrid/'
    if not os.path.exists(downloads_dir):
        os.mkdir(downloads_dir)
```

so, now all images are saved in '/tmp/appgrid/'.

I don't know what will happen when I update the app. Is there any way to override this?